# Could my friend run my iPhone App without jailbreak?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have done my iOS app, but I don't want to submit to App Store.
Shall I pass it to my friend and run on his iPhone without jailbroken?
I heard it has some certain certificate allow other guys to run it.

I have developer account.

would you please provide some materials if have some ways to achieve it in legal.

### Edit my question:

what is proper way to run the application on iPhone for testing with my remote designer? That is, he can transfer the application via itune, not xcode.

Comment: who down vote, please stand up and explain. don't be the chicken, stand up.

Comment: _don't be chicken_... it is really funny! what would you like to do with them? kill their batteries in their mice? however I guess it is downvoted because it seems you haven't read the developer documentation properly to find the way to do it.

Comment: yep, do nothing for them anyway,Some people like this. I have read the doc, but it's very general steps. I have experience on submitting app to app store, but no experience on remote team working with graphic designer who has not has xcode. Ask him to install XCode... forget about this way. If very common case, I think  it should be easy to show me steps. not just give me www.google.com, no point.

Comment: maybe the question in the title was wrong. because you also know _you could do it_ but you would really like to know _how you could do it_, didn't you? if I were you, I would have asked the following question: _what is proper way to share the application for testing with remote team members?_ or something like this. but this is just my private opinion.

Comment: good suggestion. if ppl can point out my fault, I am pleased to listen to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register his UDID in apple developer portal. Then you can install your app on his phone from Xcode.

Comment: ...or via the testflight site if his friend is far away from him.

Comment: @holex, right, my designer is in other country, far away from me.

Comment: @grasGendarme, do you mean he cannot install directly via itune, and must have xcode?

Comment: Or after registering the UDID, you can get a mobileprovision file, he adds that to itunes, then he adds the ipa for your app, and then he can sync

Comment: @iAsk, the **[testflight](http://testflightapp.com/)** looks better solution because we don't know how large the `.ipa` file and sending it to your designer via email might be not possible and the **[testflight](http://testflightapp.com/)** can handle `.ipa` files up to 800 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute your application using standard developer account certificate ($99), but it is limited to 100 devices.

Below is the documentation from Apple:

> iOS developers enrolled in the Standard Program can also distribute an
>   app outside of the App Store on up to 100 different devices for
>   testing purposes only. To use ad hoc distribution, create an archive
>   of your app, or have a teammate send you an iOS App Store Package
>   (.ipa) of the archived app.
>
> You distribute your app by providing the .ipa file for users to
>   install on their devices. Because you select a valid ad hoc
>   provisioning profile to archive the app, users don’t need to install
>   the profile on their device, only the .ipa file. Users can use iTunes
>   to install the app on their devices. If users want to use Xcode to
>   install the app on their device, share the archive as an .xcarchive
>   file package.

Detail documentation is found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH31-SW1)

Comment: thanks, I have submitted app store before, but take long time to review from apple. And my program is still in developing, not completely finish yet, so no way to submit apple now.